# OUT OF or OUTSIDE my area of responsibility?

Tags: differences, prepositions

> Do you think there any differences in meaning between the prepositions
>   **out of** and **outside** when talking about '**no longer involved in something** or **not part of something**'?
>
> If there are any, please tell me which preposition would you prefer to
>   use?

... ... ...

These are some sentences that I can't see any difference in their meaning if they go with 'out of' or with 'outside'.

1. The matter is out of/outside **my area of responsibility**.
2. I'm afraid that would be out of/outside **my job description**.
3. I got out of/outside **the habit of riding my bike to work**.
4. Keep endangered young people out of/outside **a life of crime**.
5. You may do as you wish out of/outside **working hours**.

Comment: Recently when I corrected a faculty who used "Think outside (the) box."  he searched all sources and gave me a piece where 'outside' is used. I still believe, "thinking out of box' is more correct.

Comment: Yes. In some contexts, only one of those will be correct and the other will be wrong or not idiomatic. -- Also, you have also split the question wrongly. For example: *John is [out] [of the team]* is the correct analysis, but *John is [out of] the team* is incorrect. == Also *John is [out] [of the team]* is idiomatic in its meaning of *John is no longer a member of the team*, but *John is outside the team* is strange and would require a particular context. Please give an example of each phase in a sentence that has some context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for adding examples:

**Out**, is a noun (*rare except in specialised use*), adjective, adverb, verb, and preposition. **It tends to indicate motion or change,** e.g. He went out [of the house] = He exited the house. The light went out = the light extinguished.

**Outside**, is a noun, adjective, adverb, and preposition and **tends to indicate place.** e.g. He went outside (adv.) = He exited. As an adverb it means “to the outside”.

A: I note that you still seem to be parsing the sentence wrongly.

B: In 1a, and 5a you can say “outside of”

C: In the following, **the most literal meaning** has been taken.

1 The matter is out of my area of responsibility. = The matter *has been removed from* my area of responsibility.

1a The matter is outside my area of responsibility. = My area responsibility does not include the matter.

2 I'm afraid that would be out of my job description. = (Not very idiomatic) I'm afraid that would be *removed from* my job description.

2a I'm afraid that would be outside my job description. = I'm sorry but that is not part of my job description.

3 I got out of the habit of riding my bike to work. = I *lost* the habit of riding my bike to work.

3a I got outside the habit of riding my bike to work. – Not idiomatic… it is also meaningless.

4 Keep endangered young people out of a life of crime. = Keep endangered young people *away from* a life of crime.

4a Keep endangered young people outside a life of crime. = (Not very idiomatic) Do not let endangered young people enter into a life of crime.

5 You may do as you wish out of working hours. = (Not very idiomatic)

5a You may do as you wish outside working hours. You may do as you wish when you are not working.